# Time Complexity while deleting last element from arraylist and linkedlist

Tags: java, list

1st Part :-

I was reading in the book - "Data Structure and Algorithms made easy in Java" that the time complexity for deleting the last element from Linkedlist and Arraylist is O(n). But the Linkedlist internally implements DoublyLinkedlist so the time complexity should be O(1) and similarly for Arraylist as it internally implement Array it should be O(1).

2nd Part :-

It also says that the insertion of an element at the ending of a linkedlist has a time complexity of O(n) but the linkedlist maintains pointers both at the end and at the front. So it this statement correct ? Moreover it says that the time complexity to insert an element in an arraylist at the end is O(1) if array is not full and O(n) if the array is full. Why O(n) if the array is full ?

Thanks for answering the 1st part . Can anyone please also explain the 2nd part. Thanks :)

Comment: The book is wrong, you are correct. 16% of reviews on Amazon say the book has lots of errors, and give it one or two stars. I think it's a good time to get yourself a better book.

Comment: Is the book referring to the java.util classes with those names, or data structures of the same name but a different implementation provided in the book?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It depends on what methods you're calling.

A glance at the implementation shows that if you're calling `LinkedList.removeLast()`, that's O(1). The LinkedList maintains pointers both to the first and last node in the list. So it doesn't have to traverse the list to get to the last node.

Calling `LinkedList.remove(index)` with the index of the last element is also O(1), because it traverses the list from the closest end. [Noted by user @andreas in comment below.]

But if you're calling `LinkedList.remove(Object)`, then there's an O(n) search for the first matching node.

Similarly, for ArrayList, if you're calling `ArrayList.remove(index)` with the index of the last element, then that's O(1). For all other indices, there's a `System.arrayCopy()` call that can be O(n) -- but that's skipped entirely for the last element.

But if you call `ArrayList.remove(Object)`, then again there's an O(n) search for the first matching node.

Comment: Even `linkedList.remove(lastIndex)` is _O(1)_, since [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) will search backwards for the index: *Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning **or the end**, whichever is closer to the specified index.*

Comment: @Andreas: Good point; added in answer above, with attribution.

Comment: @AndyThomas Can u plz also explain the 2nd part of my question. Thanks

Comment: @user3747182 - For your second question, inserting at the end of a `java.util.LinkedList` is O(1). Inserting at the end of an ArrayList can be O(n) because if the underlying array is full, its contents must be copied in O(n) to a new, larger array [see `ArrayList.grow(minCapacity)`]. ... By the way, I see that you have asked six questions but not accepted any answers. You can accept one answer to a question by clicking the checkmark to the left. You can vote for any number of answers by clicking the up-arrow to the left.